# VBScript get MIcroseconds

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

Does anyone knows how to get microsecond value in VBScript (Classic ASP) without using SQL Queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am still unabled to get micro precision but i can get milliseconds precision by using JSCRIPT

```
<script language=jscript runat=server>
function miliseconds() { var d = new Date(); return d.getTime(); }
</script>
```

then call the functions to get miliseconds precision :) hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the Timer() function.

See http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/func_timer.asp.

Comment: That will only get milliseconds. A microsecond is equal to 1/1000 millisecond.